# Marketing Cloud Users not Integrated to Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, user-management

I understand that in order to connect Sales Cloud to Marketing Cloud you need to setup Users in both systems and integrate them in order for data to transfer between systems.

However, outside of these two users, is it okay for all other Users to be created and NOT integrated? I want to confirm that I can  have Marketing Cloud Users who don't have a Salesforce licence? Tthey still need to be able to use Salesforce data for all of their usual day-to-day tasks.

Is there any MC functionality that they wouldn't have?

Is there any Salesforce documentation I can quote for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to integrate users who need to perform Marketing Cloud Sends from within Sales Cloud. Sales Cloud data in Synchronised Data Extensions will be available to all Marketing Cloud users (depending on roles and permissions) -- and also those who do not have a user in Sales Cloud as Marketing Cloud requires a separate log-in.

They will also be able to make use of Salesforce Data entry events and activities in Journey Builder, as these are utilising the integration user.

So no major limits from Marketing Cloud perspective.

Comment: I believe one limitation on Marketing Cloud side is sending manual emails (i.e. not Journey Builder) to Salesforce Campaigns or Reports. This can only be done by Salesforce integrated users.